# Подскажите в чём проблема. Есть класс Test в котором есть функции на бд и в index.php,я вызываю одну из этих функций, но появляется проблема

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]    //function.php

```
<?php
 class Test{

 public function db_connect(){
    require("config.php");
    $conn=new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    if($conn->connect_errno){
        echo "Connect failed".$conn->connect_error;
        exit();
    }
    return $conn;
}

//  function tableBook()
// {   
//     $link = db_connect();
//     $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_book AS A JOIN table_authorsOfBook AS B ON A.IdBook = B.IdBook JOIN table_authors AS C ON B.IdAuthor = C.IdAuthor WHERE A.IdBook = B.IdAuthor"; 
//     $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
//     $authors = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
//     return $authors;
// }
    function tableGetComponent($book_id,$table,$column)
{
    $link = db_connect();
    if(!$link){
        echo "ERROR!";
    }
    if(!is_numeric($book_id)) exit();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_book AS Book
        JOIN table_authorsOfBook AS AuthorBook ON AuthorBook.IdBook=Book.IdBook
        JOIN table_authors AS Author ON Author.IdAuthor=AuthorBook.IdAuthor 
        JOIN table_genreOfBook AS GenreBook ON GenreBook.idBook=Book.IdBook
        JOIN table_genre AS Genre ON Genre.idGenre=GenreBook.idGenre
    WHERE $table.$column = $book_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $array = mysqli_fetch_all($result, 1);
    return $array;
}
function select_all($table_name){

    $conn=db_connect();
    $query="SELECT * FROM $table_name ";
    $result=$conn->query($query);
    return $result;
}
}
?>
//index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
<br/>
<!-- <?php 
require_once 'function.php'; ?>
<?php foreach ($aut as $authors): ?>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
      <h4><a href="#"></a><?=$authors['AuthorName'] ?></h4>
        <p>
        <?=mb_substr($authors['BookName'], 0, 120, 'utf-8').'...'; ?>
        </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="post.php?authors_id=<?=$authors['IdAuthor']?>">Read more</a></p>
        <br/>
      </div>
  </div>
<hr>
<?php endforeach; ?> -->
<?php
require_once("function.php");
$result = new Test();
$result->select_all('table_book');
if($result->num_rows>0){
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){   
        echo "<h3>".$row['BookName']."</h3><br>";
        echo $row['Description']."<br>";
        echo "Атор(а): ".$row['AuthorName']."<br>";
        echo "Жанр(ы): ".$row['Genre']."<br>"."<br>";
        echo "<p><button> <a href='/form/form.php'>Заказать</a></button></p>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
}else{
    echo "No data:(";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `db_connect()` - функция, `$this->db_conntect()` - метод класса. Чувствуете разницу? Ну и ваш класс ужасен, советую воспользоваться готовыми классами известных производителей

Comment: @ArchDemon, thanks a lot <3